# Requesting custom android permissions before they are defined

Tags: android, permissions

my target scenario: User opens an attachment in his/her preferred email-app. My app is proposed to open/view the attachment, user chooses my app, my app opens the attachment-uri via ContentResolver.openInputStream(uri) and reads from it.

This normally works great. It has come to my attention though, that several email-apps now require special permissions like: com.fsck.k9.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT, com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT, com.motorola.blur.service.email.Permissions.INTERACT, etc.

I think it is bad design to add a uses-permission-tag for each and every email-app on the market. Is there a better way to be able to generally read attachments?

Furthermore - even if I decide to continuosly add uses-permissions to my app with every release, I run into another problem: If the app that requires the permission is installed *after* my app, my app will not have the permission, because at the time of my apps installation it wasn't known to the packagemanager that such an permission even existed.

So - do I really have to instruct my users to reinstall my app if they decide to switch to a new email-app that my app already has uses-permissions for? Just because my app was first on their system??

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Are you sure that you need those permissions? K9 in particular appears to be adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` used with `startActivity()` to view the attachments. That, plus `android:grantUriPermissions="true"` in the manifest for their `AttachmentProvider`, means that you should be granted read access to the `Uri` representing the attachment. A similar pattern should be in use for all other email clients that store and serve attachments via `ContentProviders`.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare to have put me on the right path of investigation. This has really been a nagging problem for quite some time. And is finally fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now able to remove all these Custom-Permissions from my app and still able to read attachments.

Turns out I was doing everything right, except for one little thing...

... I was handling reading the attachment in two Activities. The first `Activity` - my main `Activity` - is responsible for gathering the `Intent`-information and selecting/preparing a database for storing the to-be-imported data. The second `Activity` is actually reading from the `InputStream` obtained via `ContentResolver` and importing into the database.

Turns out that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` only grants permission to the recipient of the `Intent`. As I was passing on the `Uri` of the attachment to a *second* `Activity` it could not be read there anymore - only by granting my app several custom `Permissions`, a solution I can't really recommend as described above.

My solution now is to read all the data in my first `Activity`, storing it in a temporary file and passing this file-`Uri` to my second `Activity`. Of course now I have to care about how long copying takes, maybe display progress dialogs and determine where I can find enough space for my temp, accessing the original-`Uri` seemed quite a lot easier.

Comment: Um, isn't the right solution to combine the two activities, so the activity receiving the `Uri` is the activity doing the displaying?

Comment: Well, it's actually a lot more than just displaying the attachment. The first `Activity` is like a main-menu to the user. This is where all the intialising is done, the main menu is displayed and there's a lot of stuff for maintenance, managing location and creation and managing of databases.

The second activity is the "database"-`Activity`. Here the user manages the content of a database and is able to import from several diffent file-formats. This is a heavy-weight, too.

As both are already specific as to their purpose and contain quite a lot lines of code, i'd rather not combine them.

Comment: The user might not want you making a copy of the file, either, though. Remember: this is not your phone, and it is not your file.